# Pass table and database server to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have two database instances and need to transfer data between them. I want to do it in a stored procedure. Is it possible to pass the target table (and database instance) as a parameter to the stored procedure?

I got this working:

```
INSERT INTO [SERVER1].[MYSCHEMA1].[TargetTable]
    ([ID], [Timestamp])
SELECT 
    [ID], [Timestamp]
FROM [SERVER2].[MYSCHEMA2].[SourceTable]
WHERE ID= @SomeId
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDoStuff
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @id uniqueidentifier,
     @server nvarchar(100),
     @table nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [SERVER1].[MYSCHEMA1].[TargetTable]
        ([ID], [Timestamp])
    SELECT 
        [ID], [Timestamp]
    FROM @server.@table.[SourceTable]
    WHERE ID= @id
END
```

I know it can be done with dynamic SQL, but I would like to avoid it if possible. I've also read about [TVP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters), but I'm not sure that this really is necessary as it would require me to design the table in code as well. This will be called from Entity Framework Core 2.2.

Comment: You can't avoid dynamic SQL to do this type of work. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: It's a most personal opinion about it's "messyness" and readability. But that's it. If there is no other way then I will go for it.

Comment: Provided that you write your dynamic SQL well, it's only as "messy" or "unreadable" as other SQL. a long SQL statement written on a single line is difficult to read regardless of if it's dynamic or not. For something as simple as passing a dynamic table and database name, I would be impression if you managed to make the SQL messy or have low readability; you'd have to intentionally make it difficult to read to achieve that.

Comment: @Larnu - Followup question. :) When using dynamic sql, is there a good way to prevent sql injection when passing string such as @server to my sql? Or is [`quotename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the way to go?

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is the way to go with dynamic object names. so `SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N';';` will stop injection, as any characters will be correctly escaped. Good use of datatypes also helps; for example using `sysname` (equivalent to an `nvarchar(128)`) for the datatype of the parameters means that every object name can be catered for for does limit the amount of characters that can be input. But still, `QUOTENAME` is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completion, this is how I would write your SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDoStuff
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @id uniqueidentifier,
     @server sysname,
     @table sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO [SERVER1].[MYSCHEMA1].[TargetTable]' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'    ([ID], [Timestamp])' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'SELECT [ID], [Timestamp]' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@server) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@table) + N'.SourceTable' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + --Seems Odd should @Table actually be @database?
               N'WHERE ID = @ID;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@id uniqueidentifier', @id = @id;
END
```